# Fadeout content AJAX just loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

All,
I have the following code:

```
$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();
      // Get some values from elements on the page:
      var $form = $( this ),
        term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( "action" );
      // Send the data using post
      var posting = $.post( url, $( "#searchForm" ).serialize() );
      // Put the results in a div
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        $( "#updated_status" ).html(data);
      });
    });
```

I would like to fadeout the data that was just posted to the updated_status div. I tried to do this:

```
$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();
      // Get some values from elements on the page:
      var $form = $( this ),
        term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( "action" );
      // Send the data using post
      var posting = $.post( url, $( "#searchForm" ).serialize() );
      // Put the results in a div
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        $( "#updated_status" ).html(data).fadeout(2000);
      });
    });
```

The new text does not fadeout after that time though. How can I do this?

Comment: Check your error console. `fadeout` -> `fadeOut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a case problem in `fadeout` it should be `fadeOut`. But if you want to `fadeOut` after 2 second then use [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay), else the fading will start as soon as the content is displayed

```
$("#updated_status").html(data).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VU69H/)

Answer (score 1):

Is it perhaps just a case problem, where you need `fadeOut(2000)` instead?